# Can I stop parameters passed to InstallUtil from showing up in the install log?

Tags: wix, installation, installutil

I have created a custom task that is used to create SQL compact databases as part of setup.  When use InstallUtil to execute this task I use a parameter for the (environment specific) password to use when creating the local database.  The problem is that the install log contains the unencryped password which is not good from a security standpoint.

Can I stop parameters passed to InstallUtil from showing up in the install log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Hidden attribute of a property:

```
<Property Id="PASSWORD" Hidden="yes" />
```